# Speed up bulk insert operations with NHibernate

Tags: .net, performance, oracle, nhibernate, orm

I want to speed up bulk `insert` operations with NHibernate 3.2 on Oracle 11g. To do this I tried

```
Session.Save(entity);
Session.Flush();
Session.Clear();
```

... in my `foreach` loop but got an exception caused by objects missing in the Session:

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: MyClass.PropertyX, no session or session was closed

Another attempt was to set the batch size:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">xxx</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">50</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1, false=0</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.Bytecode.DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

additionally I set `Session.SetBatchSize(50)` in my code an got the following exception:

> No batch size was defined for the session factory, batching is
>   disabled. Set adonet.batch_size = 1 to enable batching.

The only location where this exception is thrown is [NonBatchingBatcher](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/AdoNet/NonBatchingBatcher.cs#L63), so it looks like my session has the wrong batcher.

What is wrong here? How can I speed up batch inserts with NHibernate (without using statlese sessions)?

Comment: What was your first exception exactly? Also, if you do the `Flush` *inside the loop*, you will not be batching anything.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon added the exception message

Comment: @deamon is this multi-threaded in any way?

Answer (score 42):

Following should work,

```
var testObjects = CreateTestObjects(500000);

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
using (IStatelessSession session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var testObject in testObjects)
        session.Insert(testObject);
    transaction.Commit();
}

stopwatch.Stop();
var time = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

Ref : http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/10/30/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernate-s-stateless-sessions.html

Comment: Should I clear my caches after using a stateless session? Or will the stateful sessions pick up the changes made by the stateless session?

Answer (score 6):

All the above tips are very valid and very useful. Wanted to add one to the collection: **disable logging**. Having your SQL shown in the console slows you down noticeably, as does profiling using NHProf, auto commenting and pretty-formatting the SQL logged via NLog or log4net. In our case setting:

```
cfg.AutoCommentSql = false;
cfg.LogFormattedSql = false;
```

decreased our bulk insert time from ~6 seconds to just over 1 second. So while logging will potentially help you nail down more serious problems, it comes with a performance hit of its own!

Answer (score 5):

- http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/10/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernates-stateless-sessions
- http://martin.podval.eu/2010/12/nhibernate-performance-isssues-insert.html

Second URL having worth to read.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you clearing the session ?

I think you shouldn't clear the session in the loop. To make sure that the changes are written into the database I'd rather use a transaction.

Pseudocode:

```
foreach (var i in allElements)
{
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        ... do what you have to do with the object
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

To speed things up there are other things which may help - you have to define what you really want to do in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was about Oracle but for SQL server I was going to write a routine to take the class mappings and generate a DataTable to be used by SqlBulkInsert, but I found out someone already did this.

https://kaylaniam.wordpress.com/2015/03/13/nhibernate-and-sqlbulkcopy/

This is probably the fastest way to do bulk inserts on SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

Code below works for me on inserting several composite entities

```
 public static void SqlBulkInsert(this ISession session, DataTable dataTable, string tableName)
    {
        var conn = (SqlConnection)session.Connection;
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            session.Transaction.Enlist(cmd);
            using (var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers, cmd.Transaction))
            {
                copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000;
                copy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                }

                copy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
                copy.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

You will have to create a method to fill a DataTable object from the composite entity object you want to persist.